# Which shell do u recommend for web development on Windows 10, as of June 2017?

Tags: web-development, windows-10, command-line, bash, powershell

Each solution has it’s pros and cons, and available tools seems to be evolving. I had some issues with various solutions I tried, and could use some advice. Here are the tools I tried:

Bash on CMDER - My experience is that it is a bit slow.
Powershell - Common recommended shell/bash commands don’t work (and the user has to find an alternative).
Bash on Ubuntu on Windows - still in Beta, and can’t work with Windows programs.
[Additional specific information: - I'm a relatively new programmer. - Already read about this issue, and tried the above tools. - I ran the same command ('create-react-app') on both Bash on CMDER and on Powershell, and found Powershell to complete execuation in about 25% less time. ]

Comment: What does choice of shell have to do with web development?

Comment: It's a good question. I thought this might be relevant, but, as u say, it might not be.

Comment: Don't you develop in an IDE and test in a browser?

Comment: I use the shall to: run a local webserver for seving the site to the browser, to install libraries to the project directory, to commit files to Git, and then to Github.

Comment: I honestly don't think that it matters which shell you use for those; and they are not operations that you are performing often. Just use what you are familair with.

Comment: I use cmd.exe on cmder.  I like cmd, because I grew up on DOS and am fast with the basic syntax.  There are a number of cmd line tools that can be installed to supplement cmd with common bash commands, and I often use putty and vagrant to ssh into a custom dev environment where I can do anything I need to that might not be available on windows.  Plenty fast and effective for me.  I also use tons of aliases